# Cypress: Is there a way to write a command that can check a checkbox using UI

Tags: cypress

Currently, I am following cypress's example below and it works perfectly for the type commands. However, I have too many commands and I am trying to condense whichever ones I can. In this case, I only need to be able to check a box in certain tests but not sure how I would go about it. Any hints/ tips/ advice would be greatly appreciated. :)

```
Cypress.Commands.add('typeLogin', (user) => {

  cy.get('input[name=email]').type(user.email)
  cy.get('input[name=password]').type(user.password)
  cy.get('input[name=checkbox]').check(user.checkbox)?

})
```

In the test:

```
    const user = { email: 'fake@email.com', password: 'Secret1' }';

    cy.typeLogin(user ) => {...
```

Comment: So you'd only like to click the checkbox if there is a value in the user object for checkbox?

Comment: Yes, essentially it is a form that can have be of 2 types and the checkbox determines the type that the form is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide the checkbox to use (or whether to check/not check the checkbox) in your data model. From there, you have a few different options, depending on how your application is set up. If you only have one checkbox that should either be checked or not checked, you can use a boolean (`useCheckbox` below). If there are several values to choose from, you could pass in a string to use (this could be either a selector, if there are different selectors, or a value, if it is the same selector with different values).

```js
const user = { email: 'foo@foo.com', password: 'foo', useCheckbox: true, checkbox: 'bar' }
...
Cypress.Commands.add('typeLogin', (user) => {
  cy.get('input[name=email]').type(user.email)
  cy.get('input[name=password]').type(user.password)
  // we could use either `useCheckbox` to evaluate a boolean
  if (user.useCheckbox) {
    cy.get('input[name=checkbox]').check()
  }

  // or we could use the the `checkbox` field if we always to to check, we're just unsure of the value.
  // in the first case, `user.checkbox` is the selector to use
  cy.get(user.checkbox).check()
  // in this second case, `user.checkbox` is the value to select
  cy.get('input[name=checkbox]').check(user.checkbox)
})
```

Comment: I used your first method and it worked. Thank you :)